# Layout definition. "You must supply a layout_width attribute."

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a little android app, and I'm having a problem with a layout, I been trying to find the error in my xml, but I couldn't find it...

The error I'm getting is "You must supply a layout_width attribute", but I did it and it still doesn't work...

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/nombreEvento"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="70"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/moneda"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/totalEvento"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/fecha"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope all of your TextViews have layout_height and **layout_weight** instead of layout_height and **layout_width** (and possibly layout_weight). Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/nombreEvento"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/moneda"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/totalEvento"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/fecha"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka The nested text views have layout_WEIGHT ... should also have layout_WIDTH.

Answer (score 11):

i think u have not put `dp` after width size .what why your code might not be working.
ex `android:layout_weight="20"`
use this `android:layout_weight="20dp"`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to your TextViews that do not have it.

Comment: I used to use this all the time too, but usually when using weight on several items you want to do 0dp because most of the time you want the widths to be a certain ratio as opposed to having the views to wrap_content on width and then fill up the remaining space using the weights.

Comment: As an alternative to 0dip, I often use fill_parent/match_parent when applying weights, it seems to do the same. But that is up to OP's discretion.

Comment: I've tried that too, but I've had problems with that. It usually works, but occasionally (but not consistently) weird things will happen where it can get bigger than you'd expect. I've had problems with things getting pushed off the screen.

Answer (score 3):

In my case i forgot to put the layout_width attribute to a TableLayout.

It's a bit confusing beacuse the TableRow which is a child of TableLayout does not require a layout_width so I ran in this issue ...

Comment: I had a similar issue. If you are inflating your layout from a XML and you have as the root of that XML a TableRow, you must specify the width of the TableRow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specifiy the width and height of the view. That is a must. For the textview, you are only setting the height and weight. Add

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size"` was set but `@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size` "was private". So instead of complaining about not having access to it, it apparently silently removed it, to complain about it missing later.

Answer (score 0):

you get same error ALSO when you use attribute but forget to map attribute to style

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, It worked when i Rebuilt Project & Invalidate cache and Restarted my android Studio IDE